# Using if, elseif statement from LookupOrderedRow

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, lookup

I am having an issue with the script below. I need to get the VAR @topic to read the Topic_Name entry in the DE. If I use lookuprow function and select the DE, it works but if I use LookupOrderedRows it doesn't work. I want to pull the data from one DE and send to another.

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @topic, @i
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all, max 2000 */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("Test_100720_chris", @numRowsToReturn, "Topic_Name DESC", "Topic_Name", @topics)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
set @topics = field(@row,"Topic_Name")
]%%


%%[IF @topics == "Tax" THEN]%% 
HTML code to go here
%%[ELSEIF @topics == "Accounting & Reporting" THEN]%%
HTML code to go here
%%[ELSEIF @topics == "Ethics" THEN]%%
HTML code to go here
%%[ELSE]%%
nothing
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: In LookupOrderedRows, the value used to identify the rows to retrieve(@topics) is initially NULL. Try using different name-value pair or use AttributeValue function to get value in send context. Refer https://ampscript.guide/lookuporderedrows/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LookupOrderedRows uses a variable "@topics" which you haven't defined.
If you want to filter 2000 rows, then all these rows need a common field value.
You could just add another field like "include" which has the value of "1" for each row.

I'll assume that in my code below.

Plus:
You are missing to define the row.
You have to go:
Rowset >> For each Row >> Field,

but in your code you went directly from rowset to field.

This means you need a for loop:

```
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @topic, @i

set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all, max 2000 */

set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("Test_100720_chris", @numRowsToReturn, "Topic_Name DESC", "include", "1")
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

/* insert this: */
IF @rowcount > 0 THEN
    for @i in @rows DO
        SET @row = row(@field,@i)
        SET @topic = field(@row,"Topic_Name")
/* end change */

        IF @topic == "Tax" THEN
]%% 
            HTML code to go here
%%[
        ELSEIF @topic == "Accounting & Reporting" THEN
]%%
            HTML code to go here
%%[
        ELSEIF @topic == "Ethics" THEN
]%%
            HTML code to go here
%%[
        ELSE
]%%
            nothing
%%[
        ENDIF
    
    /* don't forget this: */
    NEXT @i
ENDIF    
/* end change */

]%%
```

Be advised that as the result of this code, you might have the case that you output several HTML code bits, as you are looping through your result and @topic could well be "Tax" AND "Ethics" AND "Accounting & Reporting" AND something else.

Comment: Used a different method

`%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @optin, @i
set @optin = AttributeValue("op-id")
set @rows = LookupRows("DE-name","op-id", @optin)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then
  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
    var @topic
    set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @topic = field(@row,"Topic_Name")
    IF @topic == "Tax" THEN]%%
    text <br>
%%[ ELSEIF @topic == "Accounting" THEN]%%
 text <br>
%%[ ELSEIF @topic == "Ethics" THEN]%%
 text <br>
    %%[ endif next @i ]%%
%%[ else ]%%
No rows found
%%[ endif ]%%`